# How to setup existing Wordpress project on XAMPP

Tags: wordpress, git, github

I'm starting some work on an existing wordpress project on Github. Basically, the entire Wordpress install is on Github. I cloned it to my local XAMPP installation. What's the best way to get everything configured? I know I have to make a config file and get WP talking to my MYSQL database. I did that, and while I got the wp-admin stuff working fine, the front-side stuff isn't showing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the database you need to update the links so that they point to your local host.

The way I do that is that I make a backup of the sql database and then replace everything like:

orig:

```
www.domain.com/site/...
```

with:

```
localhost/site/...
```

And then restore it

Comment: This is somewhat interesting. I have a dump of the database and did what you suggested. I don't have an admin password though (not an issue, I don't need to do anything in the WP backend,) and just doing what you said didn't magically fix the front.

Comment: Nevermind. This worked. There was something special going on with the theme.

Answer (score 0):

In 2020 it's perfect plugin to do this. It's called Duplicator. You need to install it and after it you have 4 steps to configure your installation on which machine it will be running. It's really easy to use, see this link:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/